# Spotfire Visualization Inventory

Tags: spotfire

I am a complete newbie using spotfire, but I was asked to help a colleague to  get a full inventory of the Visualization created so far, clasifying those with calculated column and the value in that calculated column.  Currently the person that is doing it explained to me that she is open one by one the visualizations checking the columns property and copying the value all this is manually done, but there are over 1000 of visualization created so far by the company, so I was wondering if anyone knows how to get this information with a sql query because I have access to the server where the database is stored or a better way for doing this task.

Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Application Profiler and a python script to loop over all of your analysis files checking the information you want. I don't have a script ready for you, but this is where you need to start.

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.1/doc/html/diag/diag_application_profiler_dialog.htm

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/general/TIB_sfire_applicationprofiler_TechNote.pdf